# What's the fastest way to find out where a list of numpy arrays are equal?

Tags: image, numpy

I have a list of numpy arrays, each of which are from an image, hence they're three-dimensional (height, width, channel). I need to know at which (r, w, c) points these are equal.

EDIT: More to the point, I'm trying to find out where these images differ. If there is a better way to do that, that would be good too.

Comment: could you elaborate with some input and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the sort of thing you are trying to do?

Define two 3d 'images' (small for convenience):

```
In [417]: img1=np.zeros((4,5,3),int); img2=np.zeros((4,5,3),int)

In [418]: img1[1:3,1:4,:]=[1,0,2]  # different 'color' in the middle    
In [419]: img2[1:3,1:4,:]=[2,1,0]

In [421]: img1!=img2
Out[421]: 
array([[[False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False]],

       [[False, False, False],
        [ True,  True,  True],
        ...,
        [False, False, False]]], dtype=bool)
```

If we are just interested in the points where they differ, and not the colors, we can apply `all` or `any` (I'll let you sort that out):

```
In [422]: (img1!=img2).all(axis=2)
Out[422]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

and use `where` (or `nonzero`) to find the indices of those points.

```
In [423]: np.where((img1!=img2).all(axis=2))
Out[423]: 
(array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int32),
 array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int32))
```

For multiple images we could 'stack' them, and do the same sort of equality tests

```
In [429]: imgs=np.array([img1,img2])  # 4d (2, 4, 5, 3)

In [430]: (imgs==imgs[0,...]).all(axis=0).all(axis=-1)
Out[430]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False, False, False,  True],
       [ True, False, False, False,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Again I'm focusing on how you can perform comparisons across multiple dimensions.